# Reading nested JSON as DataFrame in Julia

Tags: json, dataframe, julia

I am translating some code from Python to Julia. I am trying to read a nested JSON into a DataFrame in Julia, is there any way to do it easily?

My Julia code:

```
r=HTTP.get(url_instrument_list,headers)
json_r=JSON.parse(String(r.body))
df_instruments=DataFrame(json_r["data"])
```

The `json_r["data"]` object is a vector of dictionaries, but converting it directly to a DataFrame fails -- I am getting one column for "slots", one for "keys", one for "vals" rather than the actual column names in the data.

Equivalent Python code (that works):

```
r = requests.get(url_instrument_list, headers=headers)
df_instruments=pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I managed to solve the issue with the `JSON3` package:

```
r=HTTP.get(url_instrument_list,headers)
json_r=JSON3.read(String(r.body))
df_instruments=DataFrame(json_r[:data])
```

Comment: Hi, you can "accept" your own answer as the solution by clicking the checkmark on the left, that'll help let others know that this question has been solved.